# Mixing 2 audio files

Tags: apache-flex, ffmpeg, audio

I have two audio files. I want to mix them together so that when played, they play on top of each other simultaneously.

Is there any API available that can help me do that?

Comment: did yo get anyhelp ?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of format is your audio in?
In general you can add the waveforms together, and that will give you the mixed sound.